# get the url of the first hit [webscraping python]

Tags: python, url, web-scraping

I have a bunch of google queries for which I would like to get the url for the first hit.

A piece of my code:

```
import requests

query = 'hello world'
url = 'http://google.com/search?q=' + query
page= requests.get(url)
print(url)
```

Then what I would like to retrieve is the first google hit website, in this case, the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program

I have the rest of the code but I don't know how to retrieve the url.

Comment: What happens when you do what you're doing?

Comment: Are you trying to get the link to the site or actual page content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select_one to limit to first match. Use the class r to limit to results. It is faster to use class and type selectors than attribute which is why I use `r` and `a`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
query = 'hello world'
url = 'http://google.com/search?q=' + query
page= requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('.r a')['href'])
```

Comment: Hi, its quite close to what I would like to have. the output is now: <a href="/url?q=https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_(programma)&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjXwK-OsovhAhULmhQKHd4jDM4QFggcMAI&amp;usg=AOvVaw195CmdsPkdGUcxEI5Y6RiT"><b>Hello world</b> (programma) - Wikipedia</a>. But I would like to have only the url: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello_world_(programma) (english one is also fine ofcourse). I tried find_all('a')['href'] but this didnt work

Comment: Thanks, this works! except for one example, where I am getting the second hit in google. very strange..

Comment: Can you provide me the failing example please?

Comment: It is for when I search for 'DE BRASSERIE MIRELL 2671GS WILHELMINAPLN 32 NAALDWYK tripadvisor', the result should be: https://www.tripadvisor.nl/Restaurant_Review-g227909-d749227-Reviews-Brasserie_Mirell-Naaldwijk_South_Holland_Province.html but I am getting a review about the breakfast: https://www.tripadvisor.nl/ShowUserReviews-g227909-d749227-r378667239-Brasserie_Mirell-Naaldwijk_South_Holland_Province.html

Comment: seems to produce the right result for me. Can you check again I get /url?q=https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g227909-d749227-Reviews-Brasserie_Mirell-Naaldwijk_South_Holland_Province.html&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiZxLbv843hAhVPHjQIHR99DJcQFggWMAA&usg=AOvVaw2RKICYBiAge9e7caSoA6RR

Comment: That's weird, I Will check again (Tomorrow). Will let you know

Comment: It's working again. I have no idea why it didn't work yesterday

Comment: Hi I did gave an upvote, but I dont have enough reputation? Where can I accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like Beautiful Soup to target the HTML elements which contain the URL's of the results. Then, you can store the URL and do with it as you please.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = 'hello world'
url = 'http://google.com/search?q=' + query
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Hi, this code gives me a very long list of all the urls. I see which url I need, but how do I select this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup to find the web results, then find the first element that returns a href:

```
import requests
import bs4

query = 'hello world'
url = 'http://google.com/search?q=' + query

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}
page= requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

for elem in soup(text='Web results'):
    print (elem.find_next('a')['href'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (elem.find_next('a')['href'])


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program
```

Comment: Hi, When I use this print(soup(text='Web results')) is empty, so in the for loop nothing is printed. Do you know why?